# Delete lines where 3rd character equals a number

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, cut

I have a consistent file with numbers like

```
0123456
0234566
.
.
.
etc
```

With bash tools, command line preferable, how can I remove each line if the third digit equals `2` .

eg, with `cut -c3` I can get the correct digit but I cannot combine it effectively with `sed` or something similar. I am not looking for a pattern, only the 3rd digit.

(I have done it in a script in python but I was wondering how its done through a one-line bash command). Thank you!

**EDIT:** Additionally, if I want to delete the lines where the third digit NOT equals to `2` (opposite question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this with `sed`

```
sed -i '/^..2/d' file
```

If you want to do the opposite you can do:

```
sed -i '/^..[^2]/d' file
```

since you are dealing with a specific character.

Comment: your answer is what I was looking for,
can you check the edit and add up an similar style answer if possible?

Comment: @thahgr You can use `sed -n '/^..2/p' file` for that

Comment: @thahgr I tested it with your input, using GNU sed v4.2.2 and it it seems to work, even with the `--posix` option. Not sure why it doesn't work on your system.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F "" '$3!=2' file
0234566
```

by setting the field separator to `""` (empty, just valid on GNU-awk), every character is stored in a different field. Then, saying `$3 != 2` checks if the 3rd character is not 2 and, if so, the line is printed.

Or with pure bash, using [Using shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) `${parameter:offset:length}`:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   [ "${line:2:1}" != "2" ] && echo "$line"
done < file
```

Comment: For the Bash solution, the test could be written as `[[ $line != ??2* ]]`.